# Smarty - Shift-jis encoding without using PHP

Tags: smarty, shift-jis

I want to show Shift-jis characters but only when displaying it. Store in UTF-8 and show in Shift-jis, so what is the solution to do that in Smarty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix different charsets/encodings in the output to the browser. So you can either send UTF-8 *OR* Shift-jis.

You can use UTF-8 internally and in an [outputfilter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.outputfilters.tpl) convert the complete output from UTF-8 to Shift-jis (using [mb_convert_encoding](http://es.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)).

Smarty is not (really) equipped to deal with charsets other than ASCII supersets (like Latin1, UTF-8) internally.